# ¿Como ver imagen en pantalla completa al dar click o poner el mouse sobre ella y muestre informacion?

Tags: c#, unity, unity2d

Deseo que al acabar un nivel el usuario pueda ver dar un clic o mover el mouse sobre una Imagen y la pueda visualizar y posiblemente mostrar información sobre ella.
He intentado de diferentes formas como sprites usando teclas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0):

Un sistema muy sencillo que puedes utilizar para tu proyecto, sería simplemente crear un gameObject vacío en el centro de la pantalla. Por otro lado, cuando se seleccione dicha imagen, puedes hacer que su componente transform.position sea igual a el transform.position de tu objeto vacío en el centro de la pantalla.

Por otro lado, para seleccionar una imagen haciendo click sobre ella, puedes usar esta función:

```
function OnMouseOver(){
    if(Input.GetMouseDown(0){
       // Resto de código aquí
    }
 }
```

Espero haberte ayudado! :)